# How to reverse a string in python

Tags: python

How to reverse string in python?  my input string is "Hey Gun" now i want to display "Gun Hey" as output.  I have tried using slice operator like [::-1] but it won't shows proper output how it works in python?

Comment: First step: explain how you would do it in normal language not in code!

Comment: `' '.join(string.split()[::-1])`

Comment: This is a word reversal, not string reversal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do splitting and then reversing and then joining.

```
' '.join(string.split()[::-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `split` and `reversed` (a bit slower though):

```
>>> a
'Hey Gun'
>>> ' '.join(reversed(a.split()))
'Gun Hey'
```

Comment: This example has an intention that is more clear then the splicing example, i feel that in almost all cases that this example would be more maintainable and so gets a vote also. Maintainability is king, optimization overrated.